# Node.js and versions in long run

Tags: node.js, npm, version-control

I make projects for customes in php+mysql+jquery and now learning node.js+npm angular..etc.. 
My question is, after very little of testing.. to build the project, needs many tools and plugins to complete. If version mismatch the build will fail and it takes 2-6 or more hours to update and resolve the issues. 
If I donwload something new, like plugins, for my new project, they don't work. I HAVE to update node, npm, grunt, etc. to build new projects.

Let's say my first node.js customer calls me after 1,5 years and wants a small change to project. I say it's 1 hour of work, not so expensive.
But i have already updated all the tools and when building the project, it will fail. And takes me half day to update all and fix whole project if the plugins are not maintaided anymore and repos are gone.

How did we got to this point ? That making websites/webapps became so complicated ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify what version of each plugin you want to use.

Read https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

```
{ "dependencies" :
  { "foo" : "1.0.0 - 2.9999.9999"
  , "bar" : ">=1.0.2 <2.1.2"
  , "baz" : ">1.0.2 <=2.3.4"
  , "boo" : "2.0.1"
  , "qux" : "<1.0.0 || >=2.3.1 <2.4.5 || >=2.5.2 <3.0.0"
  , "asd" : "http://asdf.com/asdf.tar.gz"
  , "til" : "~1.2"
  , "elf" : "~1.2.3"
  , "two" : "2.x"
  , "thr" : "3.3.x"
  , "lat" : "latest"
  , "dyl" : "file:../dyl"
  }
}
```

You don't HAVE to use the latest version.

Packages are stored in every individual project and not globally (unless you want to but why would you). So there is no "I already updated all the tools" .

These things have all been thought through so things will not break by new versions. If that was the case it would be unusable.